# Strange behavior when searching db for a string that contains quotes

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a method that searches a database. Part of the search allows users to search by an EXACT string, using quotes. There is a particular string that I'm having trouble with; it's called `String "xyz"`. Notice the quotes around xyz. If the user puts quotes around the entire string so it looks like `"String "xyz""`, the database row is not returned. It does return properly when the user simply searches for `String "xyz"`.

Here's the portion of code in question:

```
bool isExactSearchString = false;
if (searchString.StartsWith("\"") && searchString.EndsWith("\""))
{
    // remove first and last quotes
    searchString = searchString.Remove(0, 1);
    searchString = searchString.Remove(searchString.Length - 1, 1);

    isExactSearchString = true;
}

var result = from d in repository.GetAllTheTableRows()
             where (isExactSearchString ? d.Column == searchString : d.Column.Contains(searchString))
             select d.Driver;
```

So, `result` returns no results when the string being search is surrounded by quotes when there are quotes in the string, but will return results when there are quotes around a string that DOESN'T contain quotes. This seems very odd to me. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (searchString.StartsWith("\"") && searchString.EndsWith("\""))
{

    // remove first and last quotes
    searchString = searchString.Remove(0, 1);
    searchString = searchString.Remove(searchString.Length - 1, 1);

    //
    // Replace all occurrences of " in searchString with \"
    //

    isExactSearchString = true;
}
```

Comment: if you meant adding `searchString = searchString.Replace('"','\"');`, that doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant replacing " with \" after you removing the first and last quotes.